# Combining more than 10 tables data in to one table

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, pivot-table

In Excel 2003 I was able to combine more than 10 tables' data in one pivot table through "Multiple Consolidation Range". I cannot find the option in Excel 2007. Any ideas?

Comment: Asking for an answer to your question in your question is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and then <kbd>P</kbd>, which will open the PivotTable Wizard as per previous versions of Word.

From there you can use the Multiple Consolidation options you require.